# Is the proof of $(A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B)=B\implies B\subseteq A$ correct?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, first-order-logic

> Is the following proof of $$(A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B)=B\implies B\subseteq A$$ correct?

---

Proof: for all $x$, if $x\in B$ then $x\in A$. By hypothesis,

\begin{align*}
x\in(A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B)&\to x\in A\setminus B\lor x\in A\cap B\tag{1}\\
&\to(x\in A\land x\notin B)\lor(x\in A\land x\in B)\tag{2}\\
&\to x\in A\land(x\notin B\lor x\in B)\tag{3}\\
&\to x\in A\land\mathrm{T}\tag{4}\\
&\to x\in A.\tag{5}
\end{align*}

I think the proof is a little confusing when says "for all $x$, if $x\in B$ then $x\in A$. By hypothesis (...)". I think it should say: "for all $x$, $x\in B$. Then by hypothesis, (...)".

Do you agree?

Comment: The LHS is just $A$, so the implication is “$A=B\implies B\subseteq A$” which is obvious, right?

Comment: @MPW I am asking if the proof is correct. But thanks for the clarification!

Comment: For T do you mean true (1)? If so, everything seems correct.

Comment: @GarethMa yes, it represents "True". Oh but the proof starts by assuming the thesis, which is not allowed, right?

Comment: You didn't assume the thesis right? Well, at least you didn't use it, so you can remove the line after "Proof:". And since $x\in (\cdots) \implies x \in A$, $(\cdots) \subset A$ (How to do subset with equality)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stuff after "Proof:" is not needed at all, as you do not need to assume that. Instead, you should use the given statement $(A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B)=B$.

Other than that, every step is clear and is easy to follow, and it looks great :)

Perhaps add a line "since $x \in (\cdots) \implies x \in A$, $\cdots \subseteq A$".

Also can someone teach me how to align equations lol

$$\forall x \in B,$$
$$x \in B \implies x \in (A\setminus B)\cup(A\cap B)$$
$$\implies x\in A\setminus B\lor x\in A\cap B$$
$$\implies (x\in A\land x\notin B)\lor(x\in A\land x\in B)$$
$$\implies x\in A\land(x\notin B\lor x\in B)$$
$$\implies x\in A\land\mathrm{T}$$
$$\implies x\in A$$

$$\because x \in B \implies x \in A$$
$$\therefore B \subseteq A$$

Comment: Thanks!! You can right-click on the formula -> Show Math As -> TeX Commands to see how I aligned the math. Oh, and a gift for you: $\ddot\smile$.